# Running PLSR predictions parallel in R using foreach

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Users,

I am looking for a solution to "parallelize" my PLSR predictions in order to save pprocessing time. I was trying to use the "foreach" construct with "doPar" (cf. 2nd part of code below), but I was unable to allocate the predicted values as well as the model performance parameters (RMSEP) to the output variable.

The code:

```
set.seed(10000)   # generate some data...
mat <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
y <- as.matrix(mat[,1], drop=F)
x <- mat[,2:100]
eD <- dist(x, method = "euclidean")  # distance matrix to find close samples
eDm <- as.matrix(eD)
kns <- matrix(NA,nrow(x),10)  # empty matrix to allocate 10 closest samples
for (i in 1:nrow(eDm)) {   # identify closest samples in a loop and allocate to kns
     kns[i,] <- head(order(eDm[,i]), 11)[-1]
}
```

So far I consider the code as "safe", but the next part is challenging me, since I never used the "foreach" construct before:

```
  library(pls)
    library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)
    cl <- makeCluster(2)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    out <- foreach(j = 1:nrow(mat), .combine="rbind", .packages="pls") %dopar% {
                    pls <- plsr(y ~ x, ncomp=5, validation="CV", , subset=kns[j,])
                    predict(pls, ncomp=5, newdata=x[j,,drop=F])
                    RMSEP(pls, estimate="CV")$val[1,1,5]
    }
    stopCluster(cl)
```

As I understand, the code line starting with "RMSEP(pls,..." is simply overwriting the previously written data from the "predict" code line. Somehow I was assuming the `.combine` option would take care of this?

Many thanks for your help!

Best, Chega

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return two objects from the body of a `foreach` loop, you need to put them into an object such as a list:

```
out <- foreach(j = 1:nrow(mat), .packages="pls") %dopar% {
    pls <- plsr(y ~ x, ncomp=5, validation="CV", , subset=kns[j,])
    list(p=predict(pls, ncomp=5, newdata=x[j,,drop=F]),
         r=RMSEP(pls, estimate="CV")$val[1,1,5])
}
```

Only the "final value" of the loop body is returned to the master and then processed by the `.combine` function.

Note that I removed the `.combine` argument so that the result will be a list of lists of length 2.  It's not clear to me that `rbind` is the appropriate function to use to process the results.

Comment: @ Steve Weston: Many thanks, your solution/correction did it! This saved me hours of (serial) computing time. Regarding the .combine="rbind" - I like to have the results organized in columns, that's why...

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was originally answered, the pls package has been modified to [allow the cross-validation to be run in parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-packages/2013/001383.html). The implementation is trivially easy--simply a matter of defining either a persistent cluster, or the number of cores to use in a transient cluster, in `pls.options`.

If transient clusters are used, implementation literally requires only two lines of code:

```
library(parallel) 
pls.options(parallel=NumberOfCoresToUse)
```

No changes to the output variables are needed.

I haven't checked whether parallelizing at the calibration level, as in the question, would be more efficient. I suspect it would be, particularly when the number of calibration iterations is much larger than the number of cross-validation steps (especially when the number of CVs isn't a multiple of the number of cores used), but this approach is so straightforward that the extra coding effort may not be worth it.